# NHibernate (References) OneToMany

Tags: nhibernate

I have:

```
DailyWorkTimeMapping()
{
....
     References(x => x.Employee);
}
```

So, when I do:

```
var x = new DailyWorkTime()
{
    Employee = new Employee()
       {
          Id = IdFromAnExistingEmployee,
       };

}
```

and when I call `SaveOrUpdate` I get the following error:

> NHibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or
>   set cascade action for the property to something that would make it
>   autosave. Type: ProjectTracker.Domain.Employees.Employee, Entity:
>   ProjectTracker.Domain.Employees.Employee    bei
>   NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.GetEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(String
>   entityName, Object entity, ISessionImplementor session)

Any ideas?

Comment: the error itself is tells you that you are attaching a non saved entity `Employee` to your main entity `DailyWorkTime`. You need to either use cascade on the relation or save `Employee` before attaching it to `DailyWorkTime`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call save on the `DailyWorkTime` instance you need to flag the Employee property as cascading.

```
References(x => x.Employee).Cascade.All();
```

Alternatively you can save the `Employee` object before you save the `DailyWorkTime`

```
var normalHours = new DailyWorkTime();
normalHours.Employee = new Employee() { Id = 1234};
session.SaveOrUpdate(normalHours.Employee);
session.SaveOrUpdate(normalHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

in you mapping from OneToMany on the Employee table.  Set the mapping as inverse.  This will mean the the child controls the save.

Comment: Thanks to all. The problem was that i make use of two different sessions.

Comment: The problem was that i use two different sessions.